# Textbook literature on Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups

I'm a student that wants to get to know Lie groups. I know a bit about manifolds and a bit about groups, but nothing about topological groups or such things. Can you suggest a textbook that covers the matter rather explicitly and in rather basic steps?

Comment: You should tell us something about your bakgroun, an your goals!

Comment: I'm doing numerical time integration on Lie groups and want to understand them better (or at all). The Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff formula is especially interesting (and its proof).

Comment: This is a good book- Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction  By Brian Hall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend just reading the chapters in either Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds", or Loring Tu's "An introduction to manifolds", or both! This seems appropriate for your background and a good place to start.